# How to display filename or custom text for ActiveStorage object in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I have included an ActiveStorage attribute from my model in RailsAdmin as follows:

```
config.model 'Employee' do
      list do
        field :resume, :active_storage
      end
end
```

This works but it displays the ActiveStorage object in the list view:

[image]

I would prefer to show the filename or some other text instead while still being able to click the text and download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out as follows:

```
field :resume, :active_storage do
  pretty_value do
    if value
      path = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(value, only_path: true)
      bindings[:view].content_tag(:a, value.filename, href: path)
    end
  end
```